RDS Proxy Fails to Connect to MySQL Instance – Resolved by Creating a New Proxy
I'm facing an issue where an RDS Proxy suddenly started failing to connect to a MySQL instance. This happened without any changes to the proxy configuration or the MySQL instance. After troubleshooting, I resolved the problem by creating a new RDS Proxy with the same settings and configuration. The new proxy works perfectly, but the original one didn’t.
Details:
RDS Proxy: SomeName
MySQL Instance: SomeName
AWS Region: us-east-1
Error Messages:
Connection Error: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2.
RDS Proxy Log:
2024-08-05T05:35:52.656Z \[INFO\] \[dbConnection=2042561769\] The database connection closed. Reason: There were too many idle connections in the connection pool. A new slot in the connection pool is now available.
What Happened:
This issue occurred suddenly on August 5th, with no prior changes made to the proxy or the MySQL instance.
The logs show that multiple database connections were closed due to "too many idle connections in the connection pool," which may be related to the failure.
Network & Security Configuration:

DNS Resolution: Verified that the DNS resolution for the RDS Proxy endpoint was functioning correctly.
Security Groups: Checked that the security groups associated with the RDS Proxy allowed inbound traffic on port 3306 from my client’s IP address.
Network ACLs: Ensured that the network ACLs and firewall rules were correctly configured to permit traffic.

Direct Connection:
I attempted to connect directly to the MySQL instance using the same credentials but on port 3406 (the MySQL instance's port). This connection worked without any issues, confirming that the database itself and the credentials were correct.
Reviewing Logs:
I checked the RDS Proxy logs and MySQL error logs. The RDS Proxy logs indicated that there were too many idle connections in the connection pool, but there were no other obvious errors that pointed directly to the root cause of the issue.
Creating a New RDS Proxy:
Finally, I created a new RDS Proxy with the exact same settings and configuration. To my surprise, the new proxy connected to the MySQL instance without any issues.
Questions:
What could cause an RDS Proxy to fail while another with the same configuration works?
Is the error about "too many idle connections in the connection pool" significant? Could it have led to the failure?
Could this be related to internal state, misconfiguration, or something else with the original proxy?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
